# postgresql Insert query takes too long before return

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing, insert

There is a postgresql insert query called from python application. It takes too long (150 - 200 milliseconds).
There is some procedures that are done in it trigger. Also another table is manipulated in its triggers.
But I have monitored all of them. The last manages task is performed at most in 10 milliseconds.

There are some indexes defined in my tables. So maybe the reason is reindexing service. But as far as I know, reindexing is done asynchronously.

So how the rest of the time is consumed?
It is now a bottleneck in my application and I have to eliminate the extra time wasting in the db. But how?

Comment: The application is very big and it is working for many years. We are just maintaining it

Comment: Turning off indexing makes insert faster, but select slower.

Comment: Profile your python code, it might be setting up connections etc that's taking up bulk of the time allocation.